# r - data formatting into unique keys over time filled by a value

Tags: r, formatting, data-cleaning

I am sure there exists a way to do this, but I am certainly not finding it anywhere, or I do not know how to concisely ask the right questions to find a good answer, so my data frame has the following structure ...

```
> head(df)
        city      state  year   population    stat1 stat2 stat3 stat4 stat5
1       BESSEMER     1    1      31509 0.3808436            0 0.63473928   2.8563268    9.5528262
2     BIRMINGHAM     1    1     282081 0.3119671            0 0.97489728   6.0266377    9.1321287
3 MOUNTAIN BROOK     1    1      18221 0.0000000            0 0.05488173   0.2744086    0.4390538
4      FAIRFIELD     1    1      12978 0.1541069            0 0.46232085   3.0050855    9.8628448
5     GARDENDALE     1    1       7828 0.2554931            0 0.00000000   0.7664793    1.2774655
6          LEEDS     1    1       7865 0.2542912            0 0.12714558   1.5257470   13.3502861
  stat6      stat6 stat7 stat8 stat9 cluster
1     26.976419     53.54026  5.712654                    0               0.2856327       9
2     35.670605     65.49183 11.982374                    0               0.4963113       9
3      6.311399     21.40387  1.426925                    0               0.1097635       3
4     21.266759     68.11527 11.480968                    0               1.0787487       9
5      6.770567     23.24987  3.960143                    0               0.0000000       3
6     24.157661     39.79657  4.450095                    0               1.5257470      15
agg
1  99.93970
2 130.08675
3  30.02031
4 115.42611
5  36.28002
6  85.18754
```

Really all I need are the 4 columns of `city` `state` `year` and `agg`

My end goal is to just make a plot each unique city-state pair found in the data over time with the agg value associated to it. I apparently cannot even get the data in a format for ggplot to recognize, so I just need some direction on how one might clean this data to get it into. I do have a list of each unique object in the following code snippet.

```
df_ascending <- df[with(df, order(population)), ]
unique_city_state_pairs_as_df <- unique(as.data.frame(t(apply(df_ascending[,c("city","state")], 1, sort))));
```

I need specifically each unique city state pair ... and I have a current solution which is very garbage, in that I get an individual data.frame object containing each unique city-state in `unique_city_state_pairs_as_df` from `df_ascending`.

## Potential Issues that arise

1. There are missing years for some cities
2. There are cities with the same name, but different states
3. I eventually want to plot every city over time in grayscale, with a select subset of cities in the foreground with color.

I have been struggling with this for a couple of weeks now. My hat is off to anyone who is good at data cleaning and can direct me in the path that I should go with this one. Many thumbs up coming to all help.

Comment: Regarding 1 & 2, I'd recommend something like define `location = paste(city, state, sep="_")`; define all observations you want with `expand.grid(locations, years)`; merge that in. Fyi, you should post a reproducible example and ask one question at a time. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this using the dplyr package

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
  #this will select relevant columns
  select(city, state, year, agg) %>%
  #this will create a new column with the city and states combined
  mutate(city_state = paste(as.character(city), as.character(state), sep = "_") 

#using na.omit should fix your problem with missing values
ggplot(na.omit(df1), aes(year, agg, color = city_state)+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()
```